# Postgresql - Partial sum per day and overall in one query

Tags: postgresql

I've got a table of different transactions with the according timestamps:

Table: Transactions

```
Recipient   Amount    Date
--------------------------------------------------
Bob         52        2019-04-21 11:06:32
Jack        12        2019-06-26 12:08:11
Jill        50        2019-04-19 24:50:26
Bob         90        2019-03-20 16:34:35
Jack        81        2019-03-25 12:26:54
Jenny       53        2019-04-20 09:07:02
Jenny       5         2019-03-29 06:15:35
```

Now I want to get all of Jack's transactions for today and overall:

Result

```
Person   Amount_Today   Amount_Overall             
-----------------------------------------------
Jack     12             93
```

What's the most performant way to archieve this in postgresql? At the moment I run two queries - this one is for Amount_Today:

```
select Recipient, sum(Amount)
from Transactions
where Recipient = 'Jack'
and created_at > NOW() - INTERVAL '1 day'
```

But that doesn't seem like the right way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the filter clause:

```
select Recipient, 
       sum(Amount) as Amount_Overall,
       sum(Amount) FILTER (WHERE created_at > NOW() - INTERVAL '1 day') as Amount_Today
from Transactions
where Recipient = 'Jack'
GROUP BY recipient;
```

You have probably realized this, but now() - interval '1 day' is not really today, it is the last 24 hours.  You could use date_trunc if you want just today.